# Chess.js -- How to access the various fields in .moves({ verbose: true})

Tags: software

I am an experienced Delphi programmer but totally new to JavaScript/TypeScript and I don't understand the structure of what is returned by .moves({ verbose: true}) and the appropriate JS/TS syntax to retrieve the data from the fields of the list of possible moves. For example, the following simple code lists 50 possible moves from the position given by the FEN string.

```
import { Chess } from "chess.js"
const analysisBoard = new 
Chess("r1bq1rk1/ppppbppp/4p3/4P3/5Q2/2NB1NP1/PP1P3P/R1B1K2R w KQ - 1 11")
console.log(analysisBoard.moves({ verbose: true}))
```

Move 26 in the list is both a capture and a check [san: "Bxh7+"]

```
26: (10) {color: "w", piece: "b", from: "d3",...}
color: "w"
piece: "b"
from: "d3"
to: "h7"
san: "Bxh7+"
flags: "c"
lan: "d3h7"
before: "r1bq1rk1/ppppbppp/4p3/4P3/5Q2/2NB1NP1/PP1P3P/R1B1K2R w KQ - 1 11"
after: "r1bq1rk1/ppppbppB/4p3/4P3/5Q2/2N2NP1/PP1P3P/R1B1K2R b KQ - 0 11"
captured: "p"
```

I thought that the structure might be just a list of strings. However, syntax like let `MoveStr=analysisBoard.moves[26]`, isn't getting me anywhere. When I try `console.log(MoveStr)`, it is undefined.

Would someone who is familiar with the structure and the appropriate JS/TS syntax please be so kind as to tell me how I would loop through the available moves, finding any that are checks (i.e., contain the character "+") and/or are captures (either they contain the character "x", or flags: contains "c" or the captured field is present) and then be able to access the data from some of the fields of those moves, for example, "piece:", "from:", "san:" and "after:"?

Comment: This looks like JSON. I am rusty at using it and don't have time right now to refresh my knowledge and figure out a solution, but you might look at something like this: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-work-with-json-in-javascript Or ask on https://stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure returned is a [list of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868850/creating-list-of-objects-in-javascript). Here is the schema according to the `chess.js` [docs](https://github.com/jhlywa/chess.js/blob/master/README.md#moves-piece-piece-square-square-verbose--false--) ...

```
chess.moves({ verbose: true }) // return verbose moves
// -> [{ color: 'w', from: 'a2', to: 'a3',
//       flags: 'n', piece: 'p',
//       san 'a3', 'lan', 'a2a3',
//       before: 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1'
//       after: 'rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/P7/1PPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR b KQkq - 0 1'
//       # a `captured` field is included when the move is a capture
//       # a `promotion` field is included when the move is a promotion
//     },
//     ...
//     ]
```

You would want to do something like this ...

```
var lstMvs = analysisBoard.moves({ verbose: true})
lstMvs[26].san // for example
```

Your mistake is that you are indexing into a function call. `.moves()` is a function that takes a set of arguments and returns a list of structures. You must call the function and then index into the results, not the function call itself. That is `moves({verbose:true})[26]` not `moves[26]`.

Comment: Thank you, JP Alioto